# Making mysql CLI ask me for a password interactively

Tags: command-line, password, mysql, prompt, interactive

I use the following code as part of a much larger script:

```
mysql -u root -p << MYSQL
    create user '${DOMAIN}'@'localhost' identified by '${DOMAIN}';
    create database ${DOMAIN};
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${DOMAIN}.* TO ${domain}@localhost;
MYSQL
```

As you can see it creates an authorized, allprivileged DB user, and a DB instance with the same value (the password will also as the same value).

```
DB user ====> ${domain}.
DB user password ====> ${domain}.
DB instance ====> ${domain}.
```

This is problematic because I need the password to be different. Of course, I could change the password manually from `${domain} after the whole script will finish to be executed, but that's not what I want:

What I want is to type/paste the password directly on execution, **interactively**.

In other words, I want that me being prompted for the DB user's password would be an integral part of running the script.

I've already tried the following code, which failed:

```
mysql -u root -p << MYSQL
    create user '${DOMAIN}'@'localhost' identified by -p;
    create database ${DOMAIN};
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${DOMAIN}.* TO ${domain}@localhost;
MYSQL
```

What is the right way to be able to insert a password interactively, by either typing/pasting directly in script execution (instead changing it manually after script execution)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just have the user store the variable beforehand with `read`:

```
echo "Please enter password for user ${domain}: "; read -s psw
mysql -u root -p << MYSQL
  create user '${domain}'@'localhost' identified by '${psw}';
  create database ${domain};
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* TO ${domain}@localhost;
MYSQL
```

Here, the command `read` reads user input and stores it in the `$psw` variable.
Note that just after entering the password value, you'll be prompted for the MySQL root password in order to connect to the MySQL database (`-p` flag = interactive password prompt).

Comment: Dear @dr01, not that you need this bounty, but I offer bounty for the following expanding after my edit was rejected. I didn't quite understand what `read psw` does. When I went to my local (WSL) Bash shell I typed `read psw` and got an empty prompt... Either clicking `Enter` or doing `^C` took me back to the regular primary prompt... So, I don't understand how your example is different. Or maybe the whole point is that I'll type `mysql -u root -p << MYSQL` in this empty `read` prompt and I just worry for no good reason.

Comment: Use 'unset psw' command when password is no longer needed.

Comment: Read command puts user input to a  variable given as argument.

Comment: @Arcticooling You get an empty prompt because `read` waits for user input. I've added an explanation of what `read` does.

Comment: Yes I know understand that. I also did a small test with `echo` in my environment to see who the value in the empty prompt is saved and printed.

Comment: 2 things, @dr01, I think `$psw` unsetting should be part of the script (to ensure 100% automation). Also, I think the `read` password value should be hidden so please add `-s` argument to `read` there (as you know, StackExchange won't let me edit for 2 letters).

Comment: Second point done. For the first point, you don't need to unset the variable as it won't exist anyway once the script ends (it is not an environment variable).

Comment: Oh, okay. I can award the bounty in 6 hours and for now, as you suggested, and as a principle, I've unsetted `psw` in my own WSL console (even though no password was there - the principle is indeed important).